# JSON.parse UTF-8 string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, utf-8

I'm trying to parse a UTF-8 encoded string, but JSON.parse is choking on this line:

> undefined:306
>       , "o": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://got.dbpedia.org/resource/\U00010331\
>                                                                          ^
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token U

this is the line I use:

```
var object = JSON.parse(data);
```

I've also tried with this line, but no success:

```
var object = JSON.parse(data.toString('utf8'));
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a JSON string a `\` character may not be followed by an uppercase `U` character. Your JSON is invalid. You need a lowercase `u` instead and should fix whatever is outputting the invalid JSON.

[image: JSON Strings]

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. The problem is I get the JSON from an API I'm not the owner of, so I'll have to correct the JSON before trying to parse it.