# UTF8 encoded characters not displaying properly on NodeJS

Tags: json, encoding, utf-8

When I print the following

```
console.log('\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xaf followed you')
console.log(utf8.decode('\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xaf followed you'))
```

the result rightly is

```
à¤¥à¤¡à¤¥à¤¡à¤¦à¤¯ followed you - (i)
थडथडदय followed you            - (ii)
```

When I access a redis list using `redis.lrange('notif-'+userId, 0, -1)` its first element is displayed as

```
["\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xaf followed you", "Users", "233", "some_url", 201, "Users"]
```

(note that above is a list stored as a string in redis using redis.lpush('notif-'+userId, python-list), its the first item of a redis list)

Since the above can't be put into JSON.parse because of \x, I escape the slash and then revert using

```
let notificationList = JSON.parse(notificationParent.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'))
notification.text = notificationList[0].replace(/\\\\/g, '\\')
```

Now, when I `console.log(notification.text)` and `console.log(utf8.decode(notification.text))`, what gets printed is

```
\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xaf followed you
\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xaf followed you
```

What should I do to get results similar to (i) and (ii)?

**EDIT:** From the beginning, if I do the following

```
  console.log(notificationParent)
  notificationParent = notificationParent.replace(/'/g, '"');
  console.log(notificationParent)
  let notificationList = JSON.parse(notificationParent.toString())
  console.log(notificationList)
console.log(JSON.parse('["\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xaf followed you", "Users", "233", "some_url", 201, "Users"]'))
```

the result is

```
['\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xaf followed you', 'Users', '233', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/humbee_images/cartoon-bee-1.jpg', 201, 'Users']
["\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xaf followed you", "Users", "233", "https://storage.googleapis.com/humbee_images/cartoon-bee-1.jpg", 201, "Users"]
Syntax error: Unexpect token x in position 3
[ 'à¤¥à¤¡à¤¥à¤¡à¤¦à¤¯ followed you',
  'Users',
  '233',
  'some_url',
  201,
  'Users' ]
```

I don't understand the difference between the third and fourth print statement. Isnt the variable in 3rd containing the same string as 4th?

**SOLVED:** Joe's comment solved this puzzle. The second print although printing the variable with a single \ is actually double escaped, so the double escape needs to be converted by the replace function suggested in Joe's comment.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can put it into `JSON.parse` with `\x`. Are you sure you are parsing the string (and not the array containing a string)?

```
JSON.parse('["\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xaf followed you", "Users", "233", "some_url", 201, "Users"]')
=> ["à¤¥à¤¡à¤¥à¤¡à¤¦à¤¯ followed you", "Users", "233", "some_url", 201, "Users"]
```

vs.

```
JSON.parse(["\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xaf followed you", "Users", "233", "some_url", 201, "Users"])
=> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

Comment: In `let notificationList = JSON.parse(notificationParent.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'))`, had I been passing an array containing a string, would I have been able to call `.replace()`. Cant I thus be sure that `notificationParent` and the result after replace are indeed a string? I tried `let notificationList = JSON.parse(notificationParent.toString())` and got Unexpected token x in JSON at position 3.

Comment: I got to know that \x is not allowed from the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059765/node-js-json-parse-utf-8-string

Comment: Some other answer somewhere suggested to replace \x with \u00. That didnt help too and anyway that solution isnt feasible for me since the some_url part above also contains \x and I dont want to disturb that.

Comment: `JSON.parse` should not even see the `\x` because it will be replaced before going into the function: 
`console.log('\xe0')
=> à`
vs.
`console.log('\xe' + '0')
=> SyntaxError: Invalid hexadecimal escape sequence`

Comment: I agree. But, could you please help me understand the observation I made in my first comment?

Comment: If your string contains double slashes one can unescape it like this:
`'\\xe0\\xa4\\xa5\\xe0\\xa4\\xa1\\xe0\\xa4\\xa5\\xe0\\xa4\\xa1\\xe0\\xa4\\xa6\\xe0\\xa4\\xaf followed you'.replace(/\\x([0-9a-f]{2})/g, function(_, pair) {
  return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(pair, 16));
}) => "à¤¥à¤¡à¤¥à¤¡à¤¦à¤¯ followed you"`

Comment: But, by your previous comment that \x shouldn't cause a problem in JSON parsing, `notificationList = JSON.parse(notificationParent.toString())` should work, instead of the error `Unexpected token x in JSON at position 3` I get right? I will make an edit in my question to add more debug info.

Comment: Cool, go it thanks, didn't realize that they were escaped in the original string.